# Trouble with Multi-User Session test for Windows 7 Software Logo test compliance

Tags: .net, windows-7, logo-testing

I'm currently testing a .NET 2.0 client application for Windows 7 Software Logo compliance (the "compatible with Windows 7" thing) and getting a strange result that has me baffled.

The Windows 7 Software Logo Toolkit test comes back with a warning that "application did not pass multiuser session compliance check" and then gives a whole heap of odd messages that I can't decipher.

This is all the more odd to me because the app does work just fine when run by multiple users on the same machine (using fast-user switching, etc.) and has never produced an error like this during testing or while in use. It's only when I run the Windows 7 Software Logo Toolkit that I get these messages, and only from the toolkit's log/report itself.

Here's a sample of what it comes back with:

> **WARNING:** Access was restricted to elevated processes.OpenProcessToken: Token () only   allows 'TOKEN_QUERY' access by elevated processes with high mandatory integrity label6d3d22a8 - Object Type6d3d34c0 - Object Name8 - Denied Access Bit6d3d4f90 - String of Denied Access BitvfLogoLuaPriv!+6d3d780d ( @ 0)vfLogoLuaPriv!+6d3d7f23 ( @ 0)vfLogoLuaPriv!+6d3d7f9a ( @ 0)vfLogoLuaPriv!+6d3d81dd ( @ 0)vfLogoLuaPriv!+6d3e0769 ( @ 0)SHELL32!Shell_GetCachedImageIndexW+88b5 ( @ 0)SHELL32!Shell_GetCachedImageIndexW+893a ( @ 0)SHELL32!Shell_GetCachedImageIndexW+81ad ( @ 0)SHELL32!Shell_GetCachedImageIndexW+78bb ( @ 0)SHELL32!DllGetClassObject+b5e ( @ 0)SHELL32!DllGetClassObject+a46 ( @ 0)SHELL32!SHGetFolderPathEx+2c ( @ 0)SHELL32!SHGetFolderPathW+ce ( @ 0)vf_rdvcompat!+71de4f32 ( @ 0)vf_rdvcompat!+71de509d ( @ 0)verifier!VerifierGetProviderHelper+63c0 ( @ 0)vrfcore!VerifierTlsSetValue+4bb ( @ 0)ntdll!RtlCreateProcessParametersEx+b58 ( @ 0)ntdll!RtlDestroyProcessParameters+409 ( @ 0)ntdll!RtlCompactHeap+43c ( @ 0)ntdll!LdrGetProcedureAddress+94a4 ( @ 0)ntdll!RtlResetRtlTranslations+c63 ( @ 0)ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+e ( @ 0)

Some other ones (truncated to spare your eyes):

> **WARNING:** Access was restricted to elevated processes.OpenProcess: Process (pid 0x00001780) only allows 'PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION' access by elevated processes with high mandatory integrity
>
> **WARNING:** Object opened/created in a restricted namespace.CreateFileMappingW: Section 'Global\Cor_Private_IPCBlock_6016' is in restricted namespace (Global)6d3d2590

The app I'm testing is a fairly straightforward .NET 2.0 app that doesn't do anything odd (that I can think of)... I don't use any weird P/Invoke calls or anything.

I'm at a loss as to why the Software Logo Toolkit test is giving me back this warning, where it's coming from, and why.

My Win32 programming skills are more than a bit rusty, so I'm not even sure where to start looking for the source of these messages. Does anyone have any ideas, clues, suggestions, or hints on where to start or what to try to get to the bottom of this so I can find out what I must have done wrong to generate this warning?

Comment: They might be false positives.

Comment: Hmmm... I hadn't thought of that. But how to be sure?

Comment: If the code works fine, they're probably false positives.  However, I can't guarantee it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like this is stuff the Win7 logo toolkit picked up from some other background process that was running while I was running the test. (I guess that's why they tell you to do it on a "clean" machine - which of course I didn't have available.)